# Safari 7.0 Voice Over & CSS Overflow property?

Tags: drop-down-menu, safari, overflow, osx-mavericks, voiceover

I have the following scenario below-

### HTML

```
<ul>
<li>Messi</li>
<li>Ronaldo</li>
<li>Neymar</li>
<li>Fabregas</li>
<li>Rooney</li>
<li>Bale</li>
<li>Ozil</li>
<li>Gerrard</li>
<li>Torres</li>
</ul>
```

### CSS

```
ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    max-height: 65px;
    outline:none;
    overflow: auto;
    width:200px;
}
li{
    height: 20px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    text-indent: 10px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Now when i open this in Safari 7.0 (Mavericks) & use Voice Over Reader, first few items the black outline comes around the `<li>` items but after that the Voice Over reads the items but the black outline doesn't come on them. Also the items are hidden below the overflow clipped region.
This works fine in Safari 6.0.
I believe it has got to do something with the overflow property.

Any explanation & solution for this? Help is appreciated.
Thanks.